# Fancybox modal images carousel outside onInit?

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox-3

I'm trying to re-create the [fancybox product quick view](https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/pdPNmq) idea in my own project. 
I'm struggeling to get my image carousel starting/working. 
To load the content in the modal I have to use a function with an Ajax call in it. 
I can get it started with my own custom slider or with owl carousel but I want to do it the way the demo does :)

I have two problems:

1) In the demo they have the images as hidden divs in the HTML. That's something I can't do in my project because those images are only available when I make an ajax call. I want them to be avialable after clicking a button.

2) Next in the demo they use `onInit` while my ajax call is made in the `beforeShow` function otherwise it won't work.

So my question is there a way to use dynamic images and still use the standard Fancybox carousel/demo idea? So the idea is I click an image. Next the modal is shown and then ajax/json content is loaded. From that point on there's a carousel created?! Is that even possible with standard Fancybox?

I've read about the `instances` but struggeling how that should work when there are no images present at the start.

```
// test image
  <div class="image-container">
    <a href="link" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet dolor">
        <img src="lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-dolor.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <div class="item-action hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">
     <a href="javascript:;" class="quick_view" title="Quick shop">
       Quick shop
     </a>
    </div>
  </div>

// the modal 
 <div id="quick-view-test" class="cd-quick-view" style="display:none;"></div>

 // Jquery
 $(".quick_view").on('click', function() {
        var url =  $(this).closest('.quick-view-item').data('handle') + '/?format=json';
        $.fancybox.open({
          src  : '#quick-view-test',
          type: 'inline',     
          beforeLoad: function ( instance ){
             quick_shop(url)
          }

        });
    });

function quick_shop(url){

        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            // Images

            var slider = $('.quick-view .slider');


                $.each(images, function(index, image_id) {
                    img_url = imageIdToUrl(image_id, '500x500x2');

                  var img = new Image();
                  img.src = img_url;

                  var $newImage = $("<li></li>").append(img).data('index', index);
                        slider.append($newImage);

                 });
                });
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic should be the other way. So, when user clicks -> make ajax request to get images -> start fancybox programmatically, e.g., `$.fancybox.open( [ array containing gallery items], [ gallery options ] );`